# Systemctl starting multiple commands

Tags: unix, scripting, systemd

I'm trying to use systemctl to start 2 programs with one service (if that's what you call them). They're both python scripts, I tried the:

```
[service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python %i
```

In the service file. when I run

```
systemctl start security@/home/pi/pythonProject/p1.py security@/home/pi/pythonProject/p2.py
```

it fails to start it, and the error code says it tried to start

```
security@-home-pi-pythonProject-p1.py
```

And same for p2.py . Can anyone offer any assistance for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix `[service]` to `[Service]`. That is a syntax error. Second, you need to fix `%i` to `%f`. systemd escapes `/` in instance name to `-`. `%f` can get unescaped instance name.

More detail.

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#String%20Escaping%20for%20Inclusion%20in%20Unit%20Names
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers